# FFMPEG Stitch four videos together, then add overlay to result

Tags: ffmpeg

I have four videos (no audio) which I am able to stitch together using [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034775/how-to-merge-four-videos-on-one-screen-with-ffmpeg).
I am also able to add an overlay on a single video with [this command](http://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/#overlaying-image-on-video).

Is it possible to combine both of these operations with a single ffmpeg command (i.e. stack four 960x540 videos as in the first link, then add a 1920x1080 overlay onto the resulting 1920x1080 video)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the overlay to the result of the stacked videos.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -i input3 -i overlay -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]hstack[top]; \
 [2:v][3:v]hstack[bottom]; \
 [top][bottom]vstack[v];[v][4:v]overlay=0:0[v]" \
-map "[v]" output.mp4
```